# How to remove unwanted GET parameters from URL in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, get

I have this `index` action in my Rails app:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index    
    if %w[year quarter month].include?(params[:sort_by])   
      order = params[:sort_by]
    else
      order = "year"
    end
    ......
  end

end
```

Now if a user enters `/projects?sort_by=foo` it would be nice to have that GET parameter removed from the URL string immediately and redirect to `/projects`.

What's the best way to achieve that?

If there's anything else I can do to make my code safer, please let me know.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? You've mentioned an index action, but then pasted the code for a model, rather than a controller...

Comment: Sorry, wrong class name :-) Just corrected it.

Comment: no need to do a redirect if you already whitelist

Comment: are you talking about remove the parameter from the URL string?

Comment: @BetjaminRichards: Yes.

Comment: why would you want to do this?  this allows tech-savvy people to use durable urls

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the JavaScript **replaceState()** function in the view file to remove the unwanted GET parameters from the URL of the browser.

```
history.replaceState({}, '', '/projects');
```